# Changing URLs in IFrame without using Hash

Tags: iframe

I am running a website that contains an IFrame, and changing the URL requires to add (#) among the URL, for example: google.com/#/docs

And what i am trying to do is to change the URL in an IFrame without (#) to make it more easy for users, for example: google.com/docs

I've seen that "Reverbnation.com" do have the technology to change URLs in an IFrames but withouth (#)

Please advice.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it before, but I think this is what you need:
http://spoiledmilk.dk/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page

Comment: Thanks, I think i shall give it a try, and tell you the results,